# How to make list items seen only by certain people based on column data

Tags: permissions, list-view

I am trying to make a Sharepoint site where a vendor can go on and fill out a form (there will be many forms per vendor). I want one vendor (with one admin email) to be able to see all of the forms that have indicated their vendor name within the form.

The second part of the list, is that each form filled out will be associated with a sponsor. The sponsor should also be able to only see those list items that have selected them as their sponsor.

How do I go about filtering this view or adjusting the permissions to do this?

**Example:**

> Name/Sponsor/Vendor
>
> Kyle/Blake/JRs
>
> Steve/Blake/American
>
> Sean/Blake/Edwards
>
> Tom/Sam/JRs
>
> RicK/Sam/American
>
> Bill/Sam/Edwards
>
> Joey/Chris/JRs
>
> Paul/Chris/American
>
> Mike/Chris/Edwards

so for example: I want the sponsor, Chris to only see Joey, Paul, and Mikes information. And I want the JRs admin to only be able to see Kyle, Tom, and Joey.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume you have each section for the sponsor in the list forms. so In the list forms you can apply SharePoint native security trimming control as per your need.

I hope it helps for you.